# Comparing SpriteKit textures

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, textures

```
if animal.texture == SKTexture(imageNamed: "cowTexture") {
   //do stuff
}
```

Apparently, the second half of my if statement above is creating a new texture which means the condition is never true. I did come across an answer to this problem using an enum and a property observer, but surely there's a more efficient way?!? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to compare textures, that would be slow.  Think about your problem and explain what you want to do to solve it.

Comment: I'm only comparing two textures so I doubt speed is going to be an issue. My problem is that the final texture is randomly chosen from an array of textures. In the example above, I might want to play a cow sound if animal has a cow texture. I suppose I could try to do a match on the array, but because it's an array of textures I think I'll be right back where I started.

Comment: why don't you just give it a variable saying it is a cow then , that is what `userData` is for

Comment: I forgot about userData! That might work very well...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no other code to base it off of, I can only think that you need to assign the SKTexture to a variable for comparison. So you could do something like

```
if animal.texture = cowTexture {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Where cowTexture has the

```
SKTexture(imageNamed: "cowTexture")
```

assigned to it.

Again, I can't really give a definite answer since you are using variables that aren't in your post.

Comment: I tried that with no luck. I'd would gladly include more code if it helped answer the question, but I'm not sure what I could add that would clarify the problem. For the moment I am using `if String(describing: animal.texture!) == "<SKTexture> 'cowTexture' (480 x 480)" { //do stuff }` which works, but isn't pretty.

Comment: This would not work,  it would create 2 different texture objects

Comment: Sorry about not being of much use. I just tried to take a stab at it with the knowledge I currently have, which is limited. I recommend that for now, use your ugly solution. Some solution is better than none. I would come back to that once you have a working app, that way you can focus on your app rather than a little piece of optimization.

Comment: I think you're right @Jack Baer - it's pretty easy to get caught up in the details. Thanks!